# How to load all specific Enums to Collection? (e.g into List)

Tags: java, enums

I have an Enum:

```
public enum SomeEnum {
    EXAMPLE_A(0),
    EXAMPLE_B(1),
    EXAMPLE_C(2),
    EXAMPLE_D(3),

    @Getter
    private int bit;

    SomeEnum (int bit) {
        this.bit= bit;
    }
```

I will be using in this situation '0110' and e.g EXAMPLE_A will be connected with '0', but I don't thing it changes the answer. Its only represantion of enum.
And I'd like to add those Enums from 1-3 (so in this example all exept first but i want to use this range) into some Collection. I assume with some `for` and `ActionType(i)` but it doesnt work for me, Ive just started with this kind of enums and probably lack some infos.

Comment: are you wanting to range on your attribute bit, or on the enum constant (EXAMPLE_A, EXAMPLE_B, etc.) or on your member variable bit?

Comment: Your updated question is making it more confusing. What are you going to represent with `0110`? If `EXAMPLE_A` is connected with `0`, then what would `EXAMPLE_D` be connected with?

Comment: with '0' too because its 4th bit, but like you said I think its more confusing now because I'dont have to use '0110' to use answer to my question. Name 'bit' might be missleading, it actually was going to be position of EXAMPLE's, unfortunetly i forgot to change this because in my case it's 'bit'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you added int bit to maintain the current position of the element in the `enum`, I should tell you that you don't need it. `Enum` already provides that access by using `SomeEnum.values()[index]`. You can get rid of the `bit` field and access directly to the elements using the previous method.

To access to a range of data, you just need to add a new method specifying the indexes you want/need:

```
public static List<SomeEnum> getRange(int init, int end) {
    List<SomeEnum> results = new ArrayList<SomeEnum>();
    if (!(init > end || init < 0 || end >= SomeEnum.values().length) {
        for (int i = init, i <= end; i++) {
            results.add(SomeEnum.values()[i]);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Talking about a valid answer, I don't see how this answer even matches what is being asked in the question. Nothing in this talk about range. Perhaps the context is lost that was there in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`EnumSet.range()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#range%28E,%20E%29) method passing the required range.

```
EnumSet<SomeEnum> enumSet = EnumSet.range(SomeEnum.EXAMPLE_B, SomeEnum.EXAMPLE_D);
```

Comment: This looks like the best answer.

Comment: @aglassman only if the values are consecutive. Otherwise, it isn't.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I guess that is what is asked for?

Comment: I don't. This *solves* the problem only in case the values are exactly 0, 1, 2, 3... per `enum` value. If you add an additional value between them that is outside the range, this solution won't work and makes the code inflexible.

Comment: this is the best answer. Exactly what I was looking for. I'll accept when I can ;) and indeed I'll have values from 0 to 100.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No, that is not the case. The range is not based on the attribute value but the position of enum constant. Even if you give values as 0, 3, 19, 5, it will work fine.

Comment: From the question: *And I'd like to add those Enums from 1-3*, which are exactly the values of the `enum` values located at index 1, 2 and 3 respectively. Unless OP has explained the problem wrong, this is not a generic answer, just solves this specific domain of the problem.

Comment: yeah i've just notice range() actually needs enum's **name** not number (in my case). This is not exactly what I was looking for but its really close. Thanks

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: You are right. IMO, OP probably isn't even sure why the `bit` field is there for. May be not aware of the `ordinal`.

Comment: @user3519173 Please confirm on what basis is that range defined? Based on the `bit` value, or based on position? As such, you can get the enum constant from value by adding a `valueOf()` method in `enum`, but  first clarify the question a bit more.

Comment: @user3519173 the only way to solve your problem is iterating through all the values of the `enum` and retrieve the values you want/need as explained in Mike Elofson's answer.

Comment: yeah I might not gave all info. I will be using with this enum bit number like '10110' and each bit is going to represent an enum. I answer to my question because e.g bits from 2-4 will represent group of actions etc. I've edited my question

Comment: @user3519173 since you added `int bit` to maintain the current position of the element in the enum, I should tell you that you don't need it. `Enum` already provides that by using `SomeEnum.values()[index]`.

Comment: so if have SomeEnum.EXAMPLE_A(0) I only need SomeEnum.values()[0] to get it?

Comment: @user3519173 Yes. And you don't need that `bit` variable.

Comment: Well I guess that the best answer to my question. Sorry for this missleading info with 'bit' in my question and thanks for help.

Comment: @user3519173 the answer is not this one byt using the array. You should only accept a valid answer, not a misleading one.

Comment: but I can't accept comment so I've accepted question where comment is.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (SomeEnum someEnum : SomeEnum.values()) {
    // do what you want
}
```

You can loop over `Enum.values()` to loop over each of the enum's values. Then just exclude what you want inside of the loop

Comment: Well this is good answer, I can put range inside to upload all elements into list.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<SomeEnum> specificEnums = Arrays.asList(EXAMPLE_B,EXAMPLE_C,EXAMPLE_D);
```

Comment: like i said I want to use range 1-3 not names but thanks for an answer ;)

Comment: @user3519173 what if the values of the enums are `1000, 2000, 3000`? How this *range* should work?

Comment: Agreed, this would be more flexible, but could get too verbose if you have a large number of enums to include.  Rohit's answer looks like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is just another approach. You should add static method in your enum -

```
public enum SomeEnum {

    //....

    public static SomeEnum valueOf(int bit) {
        //loop over the values and return the one with the matching bit
    }
```

Now outside you can just loop over your range and call the method for each value in range.

e.g. for the range 1-3

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    SomeEnum e = SomeEnum.valueOf(i);
    //add to the collection
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) rather than a List. For your specific case you could use [range](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#range%28E,%20E%29) `EnumSet.range(SomeEnum.Example_B, SomeEnum.EXAMPLE_D)` or [of](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#of%28E,%20E,%20E%29) `EnumSet.of(SomeEnum.EXAMPLE_B, SomeEnum.EXAMPLE_C, SomeEnum.EXAMPLE_D)`.